# setAttributes in Google Doc header failing - setAttibutes is not a function

Tags: google-apps-script, header, attributes, google-docs

I want to set the font size in a google doc header, but I get the error  'setAttributes is not a function'. I can't really understand the structure of a header (it seems), as to where to set the attributes.

```
      var style = {};
      style[DocumentApp.Attribute.FONT_SIZE] = 16;
      style[DocumentApp.Attribute.BOLD] = true;
      var range = this.Doc.getHeader(
      range.setText(text)
      var m = range.getNumChildren();
      for (var i =0; i<m;i++){
        var cld = range.getChild(i);
        var ct = cld.getText();
        var cat = cld.getAttributes();
        cld.setAttibutes(style);
      }
```

In the code above I can set the text in the header, and I can see the text in the 1st child element "ct", but I can't set the attributes. cld.getAttributes() returns nulls, so I'm thinking the attributes are set on a higher element. I just don't know which.

Answer (score 0):

#### Issue:

- `getChild` returns [element](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/element), not `Text`, thus you need to change `cld` to `Text` via `asText` and then use `getText()`.
- As for the `setAttributes` function, I didn't encounter the issue you had, it just worked so I have no clue on why it errors on yours.

Can you try this one?

#### Code:

```
function updateHeader() {
  var doc = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument(); 
  var range = doc.getHeader();

  var text = "this is the new header";
  var style = {};
  style[DocumentApp.Attribute.FONT_SIZE] = 16;
  style[DocumentApp.Attribute.BOLD] = true;

  var m = range.getNumChildren();
  for (var i = 0; i < m; i++){
    var cld = range.getChild(i);
    var ct = cld.asText().getText();    // get text value
    var cat = cld.getAttributes();      // get attributes
    Logger.log(ct);                     // print old text
    Logger.log(cat);                    // print old attributes
    
    cld.asText().setText(text);         // set text as header value
    cld.setAttributes(style);           // set attributes
    Logger.log(cld.asText().getText()); // print new text
    Logger.log(cld.getAttributes());    // print new attributes
  }
}
```

#### Sample:

[image: sample]

#### Output:

[image: output]

#### Logs:

[image: logs]

#### Note:

- I placed `setText` inside the loop to show you the difference of before and after the update of the value of the text and attribute.

Comment: Thanks NaziA. That does work. I think .asText() casting the element did the trick!!

Comment: hi @MrP, thanks for confirming that it worked on you. If we answered your question, please click the accept button.  By doing so, other people in the community, who may have the same concern as you, will know that theirs can be resolved.  If the accept button is unavailable to you, feel free to tell me. stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer